# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load not getting resolved in Google pagespeed insights report

Tags: css, fonts, pagespeed-insights

Can someone help me out here,below is my code where should I insert swap to resolve webfont issue in google pagespeed insights report, as i am not able to replace display:inline-block with display:swap.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
```

Comment: Can someone format this  Question please

Answer (score 1):

You need to add font-display to the @face-font declaration.

So your code would be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
```

See for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display#Examples

Answer (score 0):

You should also use Woff2 and woff, more than 40% lighter.
EOT is not good solution.

I wrote an article about it (in French) to fully optimize the fonts : [Optimiser les fonts](https://www.36pixels.fr/article/articles-performance-web/assurez-vous-que-le-texte-reste-visible-pendant-le-chargement-des-polices-web/)